# Rails app dynamic subdomain not working on apache and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Same question asked multiple times but no feasible answer is available yet and also the available answers just support hard coded subdomains:

I applied **dynamic subdomain** in my rails 3.2.13 app and its working locally by using lvh.me instead of localhost as specified by rails cast.

My urls are like

**local**

```
subdomain.app_name.lvh.me:3000/
```

**In porduction:**

```
subdomain.app_name.abc.com/
```

My site is on appache + passenger

and it seems that appache not forwarding request to passenger.

Am I missing something?

I followed this
http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

**Note:**

I don't need hardcoded subdomains as they will be generated dynamically and at extensive level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Point `*.abc.com` in your DNS setup to your server.

2) Setup an Apache vhost to catch the star pointer:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName  abc.com
  ServerAlias *.abc.com

  DocumentRoot /home/public_html/yourapplication/current/public


</VirtualHost>
```